# Power Query Automation in Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery

Has anyone tried doing automation using Power Query in Excel? I had this thought that of data set that has country-wise data of maybe around 10 countries. The data is to be provided on 10 worksheets. If we could make the queries in Excel and link the sheets to the queries which filter for each country - then we would only have to paste the dataset on one sheet and refresh the other country-wise sheets.
My question is would this pose any problems when the file is distributed?

Comment: Some things to consider: Do you want users to be able to interact with the queries at all (would need powerquery installed) or simply view the data? Also, will you be adding information to the data model and sending to users who have earlier versions of Excel (data model won't work in a backwards compatability) ? You could also also achieve this with pivots for example. Note: you can refresh all queries in one go with Refresh All (Button or VBA code).

Comment: User testing with 32 and 64 bit machines and with several different versions of Excel is always a good idea.

Comment: Thanks a ton!  :) I will keep these points in mind and inform the users accordingly.

Comment: I would just provide one sheet with Excel Filters and teach/tell the users how to filter by Country.  Once they know, it's easier and much more flexible for them, compared to using multiple sheets.

Comment: See also here in reference to my comment above https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/excel-performance-and-limit-improvements. And as both @MikeHoney and i have stated , there are easier ways to do this.